# Prove that $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} f(x) dx = 1$ for $t>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f \in \mathcal{R}$ on $[0,A]$ for all $A < \infty$, and $f(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow + \infty$. Prove that

$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} f(x) dx = 1 \qquad (t>0)$.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $a>0$ such that $|f(x) - 1| < \frac{1}{2} \epsilon$ for $x \ge a$.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,a]$, it is bounded there.

So we choose $M$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$ for all $x \in [0,a]$.

Now choose $\delta$ so small that $\delta(M+1) < \frac{1}{2} \epsilon$.

Then $0 < t < \delta$ implies $t \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \cdot 1 dx = 1$.

and then $t \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} |f(x) - 1| dx \le \delta \int\limits_{0}^{a} e^{-tx} (M+1) dx + t \int\limits_{a}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \frac{1}{2} \epsilon dx \le \delta(M+1) + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon e^{-at} < \epsilon$

How does this look? Do I need to add in any extra details?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice question, and your answer looks good to me. :)